# fabric: dealing with cd() in helper functions

Tags: python, fabric, contextmanager

In fabric, the `cd` context manager works like

```
with cd("dir"):
    run("command")
```

and the command will be run after changing to the `dir` directory. This works fine, but the issue is that it uses a global state. For example, suppose I have a helper function, which needs to use cd:

```
def helper():
    with cd("foo"):
        run("some command")
```

If I call `helper` from another function like

```
def main_function():
    helper()
    ...
```

it works fine. But if I do something like

```
def main_function():
    with cd("bar"):
        helper()
```

it breaks, because the `run("come command")` from helper is now run from `bar/foo` instead of just `foo`.

Any tips on how to get around this? I tried using absolute paths in cd, but that didn't work. What I really want is for the `cd` context to only extend to the function scope.

Comment: Saying `cd` uses global state is a bit misleading. It modifies the working directory, which is global state anyway, and an unexpected `cd` is only one of several ways commands relying on the working directory can break. If you want around that, use absolute paths.

Comment: OK, I see what happened. I thought that absolute paths did not work, but my paths weren't completely absolute. They had a `~` in them. Preliminary testing indicates that absolute paths do indeed work if they are truly absolute.

Comment: Should this maybe be considered a bug in fabric?

Comment: @asmeurer, far from being a bug, this is by design, check the [nested cd example in the documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/api/core/context_managers.html)

Comment: I mean the ~ thing should be considered a bug. I get that the rest is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently absolute paths *do* work. The issue is that paths with `~` do not work (they are treated like relative paths, which IMHO is a bug in fabric), and that was what I was trying. So you have to do (e.g., if you are using vagrant) `cd('/home/vagrant/foo')`.

Probably you can get away with relative paths in nested context managers

```
def func():
    with cd("/home/vagrant/foo"):
        stuff()
        with cd("bar"): # cd /home/vagrant/foo/bar
            more_stuff()
```

because you know exactly what the current working directory is when you call the `cd('bar')`. But for top-level `cd`s, if the function can ever be called from within another function (not just directly from `fab`), you should use absolute paths.

Comment: you can use `os.path.expanduser("~/some_thing")` and that works fine to get the full path

Comment: Won't that expand the user on my machine, rather than on the virtual box?

Comment: oh probably ,,, try it and see...not really sure